# Is it possible to access the "frame buffer" so I can change the properties of each pixel?

Tags: linux, colors, intel-graphics, framebuffer

I don't know if my question is technically correct. Here is what I want to do,

I'm running linux with xorg. The colors on my screen is way too dull. Its not my hardware because when I had windows my colors were correct. Neither `xgamma` nor `xrandr` is useful for me because they only correct gamma rather than contrast. I want to increase the screen contrast. I want to write a piece of code that will change the contrast of each pixel on the frame. I'm on intel 4400 graphics.

Is it possible? Where do I start?

Comment: I meant they are only correcting the gamma, not contrast. Unless there is an option to correct contrast I'm not aware of, all the stack exchange answers were addressing the gama issue.

Comment: No, it still address the gamma issue.

Comment: Believe me when I tell you, it does not handle contrast. Gamma and contrast are different.